# Approach to side-effect-free setters

Tags: c#, properties, setter

I would like to get your opinion on as how far to go with side-effect-free setters.

Consider the following example:

```
Activity activity;
activity.Start    = "2010-01-01";
activity.Duration = "10 days";   // sets Finish property to "2010-01-10"
```

Note that values for date and duration are shown only for indicative purposes.

So using setter for any of the properties `Start`, `Finish` and `Duration` will consequently change other properties and thus cannot be considered side-effect-free.
Same applies for instances of the `Rectangle` class, where setter for `X` is changing the values of `Top` and `Bottom` and so on.

The question is where would you draw a line between using setters, which have side-effects of changing values of logically related properties, and using methods, which couldn't be much more descriptive anyway. For example, defining a method called `SetDurationTo(Duration duration)` also doesn't reflect that either Start or Finish will be changed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding the term "side-effect" as it applies to program design.  Setting a property **is** a side effect, no matter how much or how little internal state it changes, as long as it changes *some* sort of state.  A "side-effect-free setter" would not be very useful.

Side-effects are something you want to avoid on property *getters*.  Reading the value of a property is something that the caller does not expect to change any state (i.e. cause side-effects), so if it does, it's usually wrong or at least questionable (there are exceptions, such as lazy loading).   But getters and setters alike are just wrappers for methods anyway.  The `Duration` property, as far as the CLR is concerned, is just syntactic sugar for a `set_Duration` method.

This is exactly what abstractions such as classes are meant for - providing coarse-grained operations while keeping a consistent internal state.  If you deliberately try to avoid having multiple side-effects in a single property assignment then your classes end up being not much more than dumb data containers.

So, answering the question directly: Where do I draw the line?  Nowhere, as long as the method/property actually does what its name implies.  If setting the `Duration` also changed the `ActivityName`, that might be a problem.  If it changes the `Finish` property, that ought to be obvious; it *should* be impossible to change the `Duration` and have both the `Start` and `Finish` stay the same.  The basic premise of OOP is that objects are intelligent enough to manage these operations by themselves.

If this bothers you at a conceptual level then don't have mutator properties at all - use an immutable data structure with read-only properties where all of the necessary arguments are supplied in the constructor.  Then have two overloads, one that takes a `Start`/`Duration` and another that takes a `Start`/`Finish`.  Or make only one of the properties writable - let's say `Finish` to keep it consistent with `Start` - and then make `Duration` read-only.  Use the appropriate combination of mutable and immutable properties to ensure that there is only one way to change a certain state.

Otherwise, don't worry so much about this.  Properties (and methods) shouldn't have *unintended* or *undocumented* side effects, but that's about the only guideline I would use.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for and it never occur to me the "side-effect-free setter" is in reality not possible as it will change the state. And as you pointed out the CLR will translate to method anyway.

Comment: Yes, the side effect of a setter is to set *the member variable it refers to*. But an additional side effect is to modify *other* member variables.

Comment: I was just thinking about the same and I would even say that setting of the member variable is not a side effect, but desired effect of the setter. Changing of other member variables is a side effect.

Comment: You *might* say that setting the member field is not a side-effect, but you would be incorrect. The term has a very specific definition; *side effect* means that the operation changes state, period. It may not affect any fields at all - maybe it saves to disk or sends data out a socket. That is why I made the distinction of *unintended* or *undocumented* (or perhaps *undesired* side effects).  It then becomes a simple question: Is this *additional* side-effect expected or not? It's not the *number* of things changing that matters, it's *what* those things are.

Comment: Ok, have done my homework and do agree with your statement. Thanks again for your valuable input.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think it makes sense to have a side-effect to maintain a consistent state. Like you said, it makes sense to change logically-related values. In a sense, the side-effect is expected. But the important thing is to make that point clear. That is, it should be evident that the task the method is performing has some sort of side-effect. So instead of `SetDurationTo` you could call your function `ChangeDurationTo`, which implies something else is going on. You could also do this another way by having a function/method that adjusts the duration `AdjustDurationTo` and pass in a `delta` value. It would help if you document the function as having a side-effect.

I think another way to look at it is to see if a side-effect is expected. In your example of a Rectangle, I would expect it to change the values of `top` or `bottom` to maintain an internally-consistent state. I don't know if this is subjective; it just seems to make sense to me. As always, I think documentation wins out. If there is a side-effect, document it really well. Preferably by the name of the method and through supporting documentation.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to make your class immutable and have methods create and return new instances of the class which have all appropriate values changed.  Then there are no side effects or setters.  Think of something like `DateTime` where you can call things like `AddDays` and `AddHours` which will return a new `DateTime` instance with the change applied.

Answer (score 0):

I have always worked with the general rule of not allowing `public` setters on properties that are not side-effect free since callers of your public setters can't be certain of what might happen, but of course, people that modify the assembly itself should have a pretty good idea as they can see the code.

Of course, there are always times where you have to break the rule for the sake of either readability, to make your object model logical, or just to make things work right.  Like you said, really a matter of preference in general.

Answer (score -2):

I think it's mostly a matter of common-sense.

In this particular example, my problem is not so much that you've got properties that adjust "related" properties, it's that you've got properties taking string values that you're then internaly parsing into DateTime (or whatever) values.

I would much rather see something like this:

```
Activity activity;
activity.Start    = DateTime.Parse("2010-01-01");
activity.Duration = Duration.Parse("10 days");
```

That is, you explicity note that you're doing parsing of strings. Allow the programmer to specify strong-typed objects when that is appropriate as well.

Comment: As I have mentioned "Note that values for date and duration are shown only for indicative purposes." So your comment really doesn't address the question asked, but thank you anyway...I knew someone will point at this ;-)